# Failed to install JRebel 4.5.1 in RAD 7.0

Tags: eclipse, ibm-rad, jrebel

I downloaded JRebel 4.5.1 update site zip, and then try to install it using a local update site, the only compatible version is "JRebel for Eclipse 3.2 and RAD 7.0".

However, I got below exception after click it and accept the license, could anyone advise? thx.

```
"eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.fullversion=J2RE 1.5.0 IBM J9 2.3 Windows XP x86-32 j9vmwi3223-20061001 (JIT enabled)
J9VM - 20060915_08260_lHdSMR
JIT  - 20060908_1811_r8
GC   - 20060906_AA
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.ibm.rational.rad.product.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product com.ibm.rational.rad.product.ide
This is a continuation of log file C:\myworkspace\.metadata\.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2011-10-20 17:45:17.151

Error
Tue Oct 25 13:29:00 CST 2011
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.eclipse.update.core.Site.getInstallSizeFor(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.ui.wizards.TargetPage.computeRequiredSizeFor(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.ui.wizards.TargetPage.updateStatus(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.ui.wizards.TargetPage.access$12(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.ui.wizards.TargetPage$10.selectionChanged(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer.setSelection(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.setSelection(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.ui.wizards.TargetPage.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.updateForPage(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.access$2(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showPage(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$3.widgetSelected(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.ui.wizards.ResizableInstallWizardDialog.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.ui.wizards.InstallWizardOperation$UpdateJobChangeListener.openInstallWizard2(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.ui.wizards.InstallWizardOperation$UpdateJobChangeListener.access$0(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.ui.wizards.InstallWizardOperation$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.ui.wizards.InstallWizardOperation$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEApplication.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Unknown Source)

"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install only the "JRebel for Eclipse 3.2 and RAD 7.0" plugin or anything else besides that? You've probably selected some parts that is not capable to be installed to Eclipse 3.2?

Comment: hi, I only choose "JRebel for Eclipse 3.2 and RAD 7.0"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to remove all other plugin installations sites in your Eclispe IDE and add only the one for JREBEL and try to install?